# Don't want buffer list to be overwritten when I launch vim with filename argument

Tags: viminfo

I have a percent sign in my viminfo string, so my buffer list is saved when I exit vim, and restored when I restart.  When I start vim with a filename argument, the buffer list isn't restored, which is what is described in the vim help.  However, it's still saved when I exit, which overwrites my longer buffer list.  This seems strange behavior.  Is there a way to configure vim so I don't lose my saved buffer list when I start vim with a filename argument?  The best workaround I can think of is to conditionally add % to my viminfo string in vimrc, when there is no filename argument.

Comment: I think you have the right idea with manipulating `'viminfo'` and that would be the path with the least friction.

Comment: I tried it, and my idea didn't work.  My workaround now is to use gvim for most editing, and configure it to use a different viminfo file than vim run in a terminal window.

Comment: Can you add the details of that to the question? I can try it and see what luck I have and perhaps provide alternate approach.

Comment: This could be a task best suited for `session`. You may want to give a shot to Tpope's [obesssion](https://github.com/tpope/vim-obsession)